# What kind of car is this yellow roadster with a Porsche badge?

Tags: car, used, porsche

So I drove by a used car shop, and I saw this yellow convertible roadster that I liked.

It had the Porsche logo on it, but I checked on the website and couldn't find the car.

The place is far away from where I live so I can't just go in and ask. Sorry for the blurry pictures they were taking from inside of a moving car:

[image: pic1]
[image: pic2]
I have more pics if you need them, but I can only upload 2.

Comment: Not sure if the pics are good enough, but it's the best I have

Comment: My guess is Porsche Boxster 986

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not maintenance or repair.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about maintenance and repair. Further, it would seem trivial for the OP to have called the car dealer and asked.

Comment: Please feel free to bring discussions like this to the chat room! https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, I'd suggest it's a Porsche Boxster, circa ~2000 MY ... Here's an image of one:

[image]